# erreur: cannot convert ‘Cell<int>*’ to ‘List<int>*’ in assignment

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

I have a problem in my function that add an element in my linked list.

Here is my function code :

```
template <class T> class Cell
{
        public:
                Cell<T>* suivant;
                T data;

                //Constructeur & Destructeur
                Cell(T Val);
};


template <class T> class List
{
        private:
                List<T>* tete;
                List<T>* queue;
                int longeur;

        public:
                //Constructeur & Destructeur
                List<T>(void);
                ~List<T>(void);

        int ajout_en_tete (T Val);
        int ajout_en_fin  (List<T>& a, T Val);
        void concat (List<T>& a , const List<T>& b);
        void copie (const List<T>& a, List<T>& b);
        int supprimer (List<T>& a, int pos);
        void supprimer_liste(void);
        int Taille (const List<T>& a);
        int acces (const List<T>& a , int pos);
        void afficher (List<T>& a);
        void test_vide(List<T>& a);

};



template <class T> List<T>::List(void)
{
    tete = NULL;
    queue = NULL;
    longeur=0;
}

template <class T> List<T>::~List(void)
{
        supprimer_liste();
}

template <class T> Cell<T>::Cell(T Val)
{
        suivant = NULL;
        data = Val;
}

template <class T> int List<T>::ajout_en_tete(T Val)
{

    Cell<T>* C = new Cell<T>(Val);
    if(longeur==0)
    { 
        tete=C;
        queue=C;
        longeur+=1;

    }
    else
    {

        C->suivant=tete;
        tete=C;
        longeur+=1;
    }  

    return 0;
}
```

I have this error that i dont understand the meaning:

```
src/main.cpp:16:19:   instantiated from here
src/liste.h:73:24: erreur: cannot convert ‘Cell<int>*’ to ‘int*’ in initialization
src/liste.h:76:3: erreur: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘List<int>*’ in assignment
src/liste.h:77:3: erreur: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘List<int>*’ in assignment
src/liste.h:84:3: erreur: request for member ‘suivant’ in ‘* C’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
src/liste.h:85:3: erreur: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘List<int>*’ in assignment
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Cell<T>* tete`, just to make sense?

Comment: In French, is the language called ++C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the first error refers to this line

```
tete=C;
```

`tete` is of type `List<T>*`, and `C` is of type `Cell<T>*`. These types aren't the same and so you get an error.

Looking at your code it's pretty clear that this

```
    private:
            List<T>* tete;
            List<T>* queue;
```

should really be this

```
    private:
            Cell<T>* tete;
            Cell<T>* queue;
```

because a List holds pointers to Cells not pointers to more Lists.

Comment: Thank you for help. I didn't notice that because i did a copy/pase of my old code (without the template).

Answer (score 1):

A `List` should contain `Cell`s, not `List`s. You probably need to fix the type of the member(s):

```
template <class T> class List
{
    private:
        Cell<T>* tete; // <- here
        Cell<T>* queue; // <- here
```

although I'm not sure for `queue` as I don't know what it is supposed to do.

Comment: For what it's worth, `queue` is the tail of the list.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi OK, that makes sense. In that case, it needs to be of type `Cell<T>*` as well.